# Number of leaves in a tree (all types of trees)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have to prove the following claim, given the tree $T=(V,E)$, $|V|=n\geq2$:
 $$|V_1| = 2 + \sum (j-2)|V_j|$$

where the sum is from $j=3$ up to the highest degree, and
$$V_i = \{ x \in V \mid \deg(x) = i\}.$$

This was a bonus question given by my professor. We were sitting on this question for hours and have no idea how to prove it.

Can someone help out with a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: I've added LaTeX formatting to your question; apologies if I changed your intended meaning in any way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Count the number of edges in two ways.

By the Handshake Lemma: $|E|=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i|V_i|$.

By the characterization of trees: $|E|= \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |V_i|-1$.

Equate these two quantities, and remember that $|V_1|$ is the number of leaves.

$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i|V_i|=  \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |V_i|-1,$

so

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty (i-2)|V_i|+2=0$

so

$-|V_1|+0+\sum\limits_{i=3}^\infty (i-2)|V_i|+2=0$

so

$|V_1|=\sum\limits_{i=3}^\infty (i-2)|V_i|+2$

which is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks! :) Perfectly understand what you did here, you helped us a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Prove it by induction on $n$:

- It's trivial for the case $n=2$. (Why?)
- The inductive step is to add a vertex and, because it's a tree, you've changed at most three of the $V_i$. (Which ones? How have they changed? Understand this before proceeding.) In the sum, then, you're adding $1$ to the left-hand side and $-(k-2)+(k+1-2)$ for some $k$ to the right, which maintains the equality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood why we will change at most 3 Vi. What I didn't understand is why you are adding -(k-2)+(k+1-2). K represents the Vk that was changed?

Comment: @Daniel: The rest of the problem should be doable. Do you understand which $V_i$ change and how they change? That will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a close relationship between your problem and the degree sum formula for graphs.  For any finite graph, tree or otherwise, the equation

$$2|E| = \sum_{v\in V} \deg(v)$$

always holds.  If you haven't proved this before, it's worth stopping to think about why the equation is correct.

It is possible to transform the equation

$$|V_1| = 2 + \sum (j-2)|V_j|$$

into an explicit statement of the degree sum theorem for trees.  Hint: $j|V_j|$ is just another way to write $\sum_{v\in V_j} \deg(v)$.